# React - How to build a custom hook?

Tags: reactjs

React hooks were just released in the last React version `16.8.1`, offering hooks for use of states, effects and contexts.

How to build a custom hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [react documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html):

> A custom Hook is a JavaScript function whose name starts with ”use” and that may call other Hooks.

So typically you just need to create another function which calls the hooks you want to use. I think the "use" prefix is just for convention, but I can't confirm it.

For instance, this counter is a custom hook:

```
function useCounter(){
    let [value, set] = useState(0);
    return [
        value,

        // an increment function
        () => set(value+1),

        // feel free to add any other functions or datas you wish here
    ];
}
```

Use of this counter in a component:

```
function MyComponent(){
    // use of custom hook
    let [count, increment] = useCounter();

    return (
        <div>
            <div>Times clicked: {count}</div>
            <button onClick={increment}>Click me</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: You should not use `++`, because it mutates the value

Comment: You are right. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create a custom hook which exports an object with the value and two methods:

```
const useCounter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return {
    counter,
    increment: () => setCounter(counter + 1),
    decrement: () => setCounter(counter - 1)
  };
};
```

and then in your component you can use it as follows:

```
const Component = () => {
  const { counter, increment, decrement } = useCounter();

  return (
    <div>
      <span onClick={decrement}>-</span>
      <span style={{ padding: "10px" }}>{counter}</span>
      <span onClick={increment}>+</span>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/z6vy6432r3)